# Pinning cmd to the taskbar

Tags: windows-11

cmd.exe behaves strangely on the taskbar.

I create a shortcut to it and pin it to the taskbar. When clicking on the taskbar icon, it creates a new temporary taskbar icon instead of using the current one.

This seems like a taskbar grouping issue.

Why is it a problem? The new temporary icon is the original cmd's instead of the one I set in the shortcut. Also, it clutters the taskbar.

It affects pinning batch files (cmd /c x.bat) or python scripts.

It's as if the shortcut doesn't run cmd itself but calls an external app that runs it separately. For example, using C++ to create an exe that executes `system( "cmd" );`. Pinning the exe to the taskbar would behave similarly.

Strangely, when I choose in the shortcut that the window should be minimized, it works fine, and a new icon isn't created. However, i) the cmd is minimized, ii) when restored, its properties aren't the default that I set (e.g. font) but set to Windows' original setting.

Related:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35096472/how-to-place-a-python-script-into-the-taskbar-without-pinning-it-to-python